# DNN Language Selector works only on Home Page

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am facing very strange issue in my DotNetNuke website (8.04 Version). I have dual language installed (German and English) in which German is default language.
From the homepage i can switch to English or German which is working fine, but from all other pages (including host and admin pages) I can only able to switch English but can not change to German. When i choose German, Page is reloaded but language is always English, if i need to switch to German, only option i have is to go to home page. Any help will be appropriated.

Thnx

Comment: Do you possibly not have all the other pages translated/published in the other language?

Comment: @ChrisHammond - Thank you for reply. yes, it was issue with translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite standard behaviour if you have not yet translated the pages from one language to the other.

Follow these steps:

1. Navigate to Admin > Advanced Settings >  Languages
2. Select the page that you want to translate, using the dropdown menu
3. In the German language column, translate the page title, description and module titles
4. Tick the checkbox that says "translated".
5. Hit update and repeat steps 1-5 for every page you need to translate.

[Here's an image that shows the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHwrl.png)

Ref: [DNN documentation](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Content/Dnn.Platform/Documentation/Advanced%20Site%20Management/Content%20Localization/Translating/01%20Translating%20a%20Page.html)